# Classic ASP FormatPercent ignores 100%?

Tags: asp-classic, percentage

The code below works out percentages for my data. All works fine apart from 100% which should be red (#B20000) but in fact is green (#32CD32). I added an option that specifically refers to 100% but even that has not effect. Any ideas? Thanks

```vbs
R = FormatPercent( objRsStat("active_beds") / objRsStat("total_beds"), 2 )
'R = objRsStat("percent_remaining")
If R =< "60%" Then
    CL = "#32CD32"
ElseIf R => "61%" And R =< "79%" Then
    CL = "#FF8000" 
ElseIf R => "80%" Then
    CL = "#B20000"
ELSEIF R = "100%" Then
    CL = "#B20000"
END IF
```

Updated Code (With Error):

```
If R <= 0.6 Then
    CL = "#32CD32"
ELSEIF R => 0.61 AND R <= 0.79 THEN
    CL = "#FF8000" 
ELSEIF R => 0.80 THEN
    CL = "#B20000"
END IF
```

Comment: You can't compare a string value and expect it to behave like a numeric value. Test the raw percentage *(`R => "61%"` doesn't mean what you think it does)* `objRsStat("active_beds")/objRsStat("total_beds")`.

Comment: It currently works as is - when changed from string to numeric it throws up a nice error. It's just the 100% figure that it's struggling with. 99% is fine so i'm guessing it's getting confused somewhere and not treating 100% as  100% - like 100% actually is read as 0% type scenario

Comment: Don't make assumptions, see @dai [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39960810/692942).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax. `<= "60%"` will compare the **numeric** value in `R` to the **string** "60%". VBScript doesn't complain about this because it's permissive by-design, but this also causes silent issues - like what you're experiencing.

You're also using incorrect code that won't even run: the "less-than-or-equal-to" operator is `<=` and not `=<`).

Try this:

```
If R <= 0.6 Then
    CL = "#32CD32"
```

(You also need to remove the `FormatPercent` function call, otherwise you'll get a type mismatch error.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've attempted to change this using your suggestion but i'm getting type mismatch R

Current code is:

    If R <= 0.6 Then
    CL = "#32CD32"
    ELSEIF R => 0.61 AND R <= 0.79 THEN
    CL = "#FF8000" 
    ELSEIF R => 0.80 THEN
    CL = "#B20000"
    END IF

Comment: Remove the `FormatPercent` function call.

Comment: Ah, thanks. This is now working (marked as answered).